# ajax innerHTML result doesn`t return html code from PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, innerhtml

ajax:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "calculator/panouri-simple/calcul-panouri-simple.php",
data:  $("#formular_comanda").serialize(),
success: function(result) 
{
     document.getElementById("show_panels").innerHTML = result;
},
error: function(result)
{
     console.log("Eroare:");
     console.log(result);
}
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="show_panels"></div>
```

when I look into "View page source" on browser, there is no html code between `<div id="show_panels">` and `</div>`.

`result` from ajax is returning some inputs and I call those inputs with another ajax, but in html page source, those inputs are not there.

They are visually in browser, but the html code is not present in source code. I hope you understand what do I mean here. Look at the photos.

I am calling those inputs names in a php file and I get `undefined variabile ...`. This is my problem. Visually, the inputs are there but no html code.

[image]
[image]

Debugger:

[image]

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint and made sure that `result` is anything other than `undefined`?  What is it?

Comment: Do what @zero298 say, if is returning something, check if there is no other element with id `show_panels`

Comment: I used debugger right after `succes ... result` and `result ="the html code I need"`;

Comment: I will upload a photo with deubgger.

Comment: Please look at updated post and see the Debugger photo.

Comment: There is no other div with id show_panels.

Answer (score 1):

Can I ask why you're using the traditional JavaScript `document.getElementById` when you've loaded jQuery and are using the syntax for it? You use a jQuery selector `$("#formular_comanda").serialize()` when you send the data to `.ajax`. Why not do something like...

```
success: function(result) {
    $("#show_panels").html(result);
},
```

Is your PHP file `calculator/panouri-simple/calcul-panouri-simple.php` expecting any GET parameters? Or anything in the POST that isn't being sent? Does the error appear in the console (you wrote with `console.log`), since the thing didn't go through?

Is your jQuery snippet, where you call the `.ajax` statement, inside of an event handler like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ...
});
```

or is it just in the source as it is?